# Solve $n = \frac{xy}{x+y}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> $n = \frac{xy}{x+y} \text{and}\; x,y \in \mathbb{N}$ Is there always a solution ? And how to find them.

This a easy question I guess. But I am missing something. Any Hint will be helpful.

Comment: Are we supposed to Solve for x?

Comment: @Rohan no ... (x,y)

Comment: Are $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @kingW3 yes. $x,y \in N$ updated

Comment: There can't be a solution when $x$=$-y$

Comment: @Ramanujan $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$ :3

Comment: I guess $n\in \mathbb{N}$ is given and you're asked to check whether there always exist $x,y\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n = \frac{xy}{x+y}$?

Comment: So we have to find a pair $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{xy}{x+y}\in\mathbb{N}$? Or that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Notice that $n = \frac{xy}{x+y}$ is equivalent to $\frac1x + \frac1y = \frac1n$. Write $\frac1x = \frac1n - \frac1y = \frac{y-n}{ny}$. Can you now guess a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming $n$ is given, and we want $x$ and $y$:

Rewrite as $xy-nx-ny=0$, and then as $xy-nx-ny+n^2=n^2$, and then as

$(x-n)(y-n)=n^2$.

So some possibilities that would work are $(x,y)=(2n,2n)$; or $(x,y)=(n^2+n,n+1)$.

Depending on ways you can factor $n^2$, there may be other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the fraction,
$xy =n(x+y)$
or $xy-n(x+y)=0$
or 
$n^2=xy-n(x+y)+n^2
=(x-n)(y-n)
$.

Therefore any factorization
of $n^2=ab$
gives a solution with
$x=a+n, y=b+n$.

Since
$n^2=n*n=1*n^2$,
we always have the solutions
$x=y=2n$
and
$x=n+1, y=n^2+n$.

If $n$ is not prime,
there always more solutions.

Comment: Even if $n$ is prime there is a solution 
1/n = 1/2n + 1/2n

Comment: There are always the two solutions I stated. If n is not prime, there are more.

Comment: If $x=n+1$, shouldn't $y=n^2+n$?

Comment: You are right. Fixed and upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$
\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{n(n+1)}=\frac1n
$$